# ¿Se puede "traspapelar" un e-mail?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, informática

Hace años, cuando aún escribíamos cartas de papel, a veces podía ocurrir que se nos *traspapelara*. Es decir, por alguna razón ese documento se colaba entre otros papeles y ya no éramos capaces de encontrarlo. Como resultado, olvidábamos la carta y demorábamos la respuesta mucho más de lo que la cortesía recomienda.

> **[traspapelar](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=P4Ky3YtFGDXX2NHS1Q8o)**
>
> (De tras1 y papel).
>
> 1. tr. Confundir, perder un papel entre otros, haciendo perder el lugar o colocación que tenía. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. Perder o colocar en sitio equivocado cualquier otra cosa. U. t. c. prnl.

Ahora esta situación me ocurre a veces con los correos electrónicos: uso Gmail y las combinaciones de teclas a veces me hacen una mala pasada, archivando algo sin que me dé cuenta. Pasa un tiempo, recuerdo ese e-mail y al ir a contestar a la persona que me había escrito querría empezar con un:

> Lo siento, ¡se me traspapeló tu e-mail!

Pero claro, me pregunto: ¿es pertinente usar este término en un contexto virtual? ¿hay alguna otra palabra que sea más independiente del material o traspapelar ya ha ganado suficiente abtracción como para utilizarlo también aquí?

Comment: ¿Y por qué no ***se me trasemilió***? No es que se me escapase, es que te llegan decenas de correos diarios y simplemente se te pasó.

Comment: Finalmente no me queda clara la respuesta. Preguntó si antes era traspapelar en relación al papel, no sería correcto trasmeiliar?

Comment: @Jorge ahí radica el tema de la pregunta: saber si _traspapelar_ cogió un sentido metafórico que haga que la parte de "papel" también pueda aplicar al "e-mail".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo creo que sí es correcto, en un sentido metafórico.

Cuando lo usas para un correo virtual y no físico, estás usando la definición número 2 que tú has puesto: colocar en sitio equivocado **cualquier otra cosa**, en este caso un correo electrónico.

Comment: Coincido con esta respuesta. Llevamos aplicando metáforas más o menos postales a este tipo de mensajes desde que se inventaron: remitente, destinatario, dirección, firma, iconos de sobres, *stationery* (afortunadamente en desuso), papelera, _envelope_ (a nivel técnico), buzón, adjuntar, iconos de clips... Traspapelar me parece completamente natural dado el contexto.

Comment: Si tu disculpa llegara en mi inbox, preferiría que dijeras algo más directo y honesto, por ejemplo, *Lo siento, ¡se me escapó tu e-mail!  Muchas gracias por volvérmelo a mandar.*

Answer (score 0):

Es falta más leve decir que un "emilio" <sup>(1)</sup> se ha traspapelado, que decir "soft-ware" por mera y sola oposición al "hard" de "hardware". Los franceses acuñaron el término más apropiado de "logiciel" = "logicial" por oposición mucho más fundamentada a "matériel" = "material".

<sup>(1) Por desgracia, en España, solemos decir "e-mail" sin traducir o a veces simplemente "correo". Los Canadienses francohablantes Quebequeses acuñaron "courriel" juntando "courrier" = "correo" y "el" = "électronique".</sup>

Comment: No veo porque seria un error. También se dice _internet_ y no _interred_, por ejemplo. Es una parte normal de la evolución lingüística que entren palabras de otros idiomas. _Filosofía_, _geografía_, _biología_ son palabras de origen Griego, pero eso no les hace ni errores ni menos Españoles. Hay muy, muy pocas palabras en Castellano que no vienen ni del Latín, ni del Árabe ni de ninguna otra lengua sino fueron desarrolladas en el Español mismo. Ninguna lengua no nació entera y independiente de las demás.

Comment: Aún si decir “email” fuera incorrecto, me parece que es tangencial a la pregunta que se hizo sobre traspapelar.